# Skype API or Google Talk/Voice in Java, Android

Tags: java, android, skype

It will use Skype's API or Google Talk/Voice. The app's front screen is very simple. The app is meant to be an intercom through skype, so it will have its own skype account and will call another specific skype account.

At the top will be a status bar. It could say: Not Connected, Calling, Connected, and No Answer.
Below that should be the spot where the video comes in through the skype api.
At the bottom should be a "Push to Call" button and when in the middle of a conversation, a "Push to End" button.
In the bottom right of the screen should be an invisible button to enter the admin backend. When clicked, a passcode will popup (set the first time the app is opened).

On the backend, the app will allow the user to enter the app's skype username and password. It will also ask for the skype username it should be contacting.
Below that is should ask for an email address. The email address should be used when the app says no answer, an envelope should popup and say "Send Message". If the user clicks on it, the app uses the androids default email address to send an email to the email address entered in the admin section.
The last part is there should be two boxes on it. If the first one is checked, the front page should remain the same. If the second one is checked, the front page should change a little. Everything should remain the same but shrink a little and at the top should be a search bar and a scrollable list of all the skype user's contacts.

If skype won't work, I would want it built through Google Talk/Voice.

Can I do that using Skype API or Google Talk?

Answer (score 1):

Skype does have an API but I am not sure how good it is. Here is the link: https://developer.skype.com/

Google Voice has an api and there is an unofficial java library that you can use in Android. Here is the link: http://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/

So you can look into those and see if they work for the app idea that you have.